# GWT Bean Validation (jsr-303) and xml config

Tags: java, xml, gwt, bean-validation

I am building a sort of validation framework for a GWT project.

The point is to reuse the same validation code for both client and server side.
I found that jsr-303 Bean Validation is supported by both GWT([here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/wiki/GWT_Validation_2_0)) and Spring([here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html)).

As my model object are generated and I cannot annotate them properly, I would like to use xml-based configuration for jsr-303 Bean Validation. However, I don't see a way of doing it with gwt-validation.

Is there a way I configure the gwt-validation using xml instead of annotations?

Comment: FYI, there's also [built-in support](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/BeanValidation) in GWT, but it won't help you as it doesn't support XML configuration either.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I saw that, but on the built-in support home page they say:   

WARNING
EXPERIMENTAL. The API may change. SOME things still just don't work.

Comment: The EXPERIMENTAL flag has actually been [turned off](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=11228) last month; it should ship in GWT 2.5.

Comment: Ah, you're right, thanks once again. Unfortunately, it does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's no way of doing this yet.